# Appending the lists of two lists of lists

Tags: r, list, append, lapply

I have two lists as follows:

```
list1 <- list(c(`0` = 0L, `25` = 0L, `100` = 1L, `250` = 1L, `500` = 1L, 
                `1000` = 1L, Infinity = 3L), c(`0` = 0L, `25` = 0L, `100` = 1L, 
                                               `250` = 1L, `500` = 1L, Infinity = 4L))

list2 <- list(c(`0` = 0L, `25` = 0L, `100` = 0L, `250` = 2L, `500` = 1L, 
                `1000` = 1L, Infinity = 3L), c(`0` = 0L, `25` = 0L, `100` = 1L, 
                                               `250` = 1L, `500` = 1L, Infinity = 4L))
```

I would like to append `list2[[1]]` to `list1[[1]]` and append `list2[[2]]` to `list1[[2]]`. So that:

```
list_out <- list(c(`0` = 0L, `25` = 0L, `100` = 1L, `250` = 1L, `500` = 1L, 
                `1000` = 1L, Infinity = 3L, `0` = 0L, `25` = 0L, `100` = 0L, `250` = 2L, `500` = 1L, 
                `1000` = 1L, Infinity = 3L), c(`0` = 0L, `25` = 0L, `100` = 1L, 
                                               `250` = 1L, `500` = 1L, Infinity = 4L, `0` = 0L, `25` = 0L, `100` = 1L, 
                                               `250` = 1L, `500` = 1L, Infinity = 4L))
```

Could anyone help me explain how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` and `c()`.

```
lapply(1:length(list1), function(x) c(list1[[x]], list2[[x]]))
```

Or `mapply` with `append` or `c`:

```
mapply(append, list1, list2)
```

#### Output

```
[[1]]
       0       25      100      250      500     1000 Infinity        0 
       0        0        1        1        1        1        3        0 
      25      100      250      500     1000 Infinity 
       0        0        2        1        1        3 

[[2]]
       0       25      100      250      500 Infinity        0       25 
       0        0        1        1        1        4        0        0 
     100      250      500 Infinity 
       1        1        1        4
```

Check if it's identical to your `list_out`:

```
identical(lapply(1:length(list1), function(x) c(list1[[x]], list2[[x]])), list_out)
[1] TRUE

identical(mapply(append, list1, list2), list_out)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R solution.

```
Map(c, list1, list2)

identical(Map(c, list1, list2), list_out)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(list1, list2, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base function `append`:

```
> append(list1[[1]], list2[[1]])
       0       25      100      250      500     1000 Infinity        0       25      100 
       0        0        1        1        1        1        3        0        0        0 
     250      500     1000 Infinity 
       2        1        1        3 
>   append(list1[[2]], list2[[2]])
       0       25      100      250      500 Infinity        0       25      100      250 
       0        0        1        1        1        4        0        0        1        1 
     500 Infinity 
       1        4
```